# (ios9) HangTracer interval is 0, forcing to 1s, while using Contact Framework

Tags: ios, contacts, ios9, xcode7

I was working with Contact Framework (just adding a contact). And It was saved without any problem (I double checked in Contact List) but recently I notice that this message appears on console:

> 2015-06-12 09:57:39.723 AddingContactToAddressBook[819:291346]
> HangTracer interval is 0, forcing to 1s
>
> 2015-06-12 09:57:39.725
> AddingContactToAddressBook[819:291346] made new hangtracer
> connection:0x332e10

I googled it and I only found a mention in Twitter, about “What new wizardry is this?”.

Actually, I don’t know if my code is the cause of this problem.

```
 -(void)verifyUserAuthorizationInIOS9andLower{

CNContactStore * contactStore = [[CNContactStore alloc]init];

if ([CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts] == CNAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
    [contactStore requestAccessForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * __nullable error) {
        
        if (granted==YES) {
            [self addContactInIOS9andLower];
            
            if ([self addContactInIOS9andLower]) {
                NSLog(@"Error");
            }
            
            else{
                NSLog(@"Error");
            }
        }
        
        else{
            NSLog(@"Error");
        }
                                                
    }];

}

else if ([CNContactStore authorizationStatusForEntityType:CNEntityTypeContacts] == CNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized){
    [self addContactInIOS9andLower];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"Error");
}
}


-(BOOL)addContactInIOS9andLower{

CNContactStore * contactStore = [[CNContactStore alloc]init];

CNMutableContact *mutableContact = [[CNMutableContact alloc]init];

mutableContact.givenName = name;
mutableContact.familyName = lastname;

mutableContact.phoneNumbers = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[CNLabeledValue labeledValueWithLabel:CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone value:[CNPhoneNumber phoneNumberWithStringValue:phone]], nil];

CNSaveRequest * saveRequest = [[CNSaveRequest alloc]init];
[saveRequest addContact:mutableContact toContainerWithIdentifier:nil];

NSError *error = nil;

if ([contactStore executeSaveRequest:saveRequest error:&error]){
    return NO;
}

else{
    return YES;
}
}
```

Comment: Now This message appear: " 2015-06-12 10:12:12.943 AddingContactToAddressBook[824:293782] Stopping HangTracer"

Comment: Thanks for asking, "wizardry" fits perfectly here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Debugging with a breakpoint on `NSLog` gives a call to `[UIApplication startHangtracer:]`. This occurs in the thread under `HTStartHangTracing`.

Th fact that it occurs since iOS 9, and that it is from within `UIApplication`, gives me a strong feeling towards Apple's new bug reporting framework in iOS 9.

This might just be the part about detecting when an application hangs.

Someone should investigate their app bugreports when distributed through TestFlight, to confirm that this `HangTracer` is part of that.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the explanation. In fact, that was the first time that i saw that message so it was very confusing.

Comment: So you are saying there is no issue I as developer have to worry about? Because I am experiencing the issue since right now. I upgraded yesterday and did not come across it yet which is surprising...

Comment: @LinusG. It seems to not always occur, and yes you shouldn't worry.